# Load Wordpress page in a div without reloading page and while changing url

Tags: ajax, wordpress, sidebar

I am coding a website for a client and they requested that because they have so many sidebar pages under one parent, that when the page link is clicked, it loads in the same area every time without the page reloading. They also requested that the URL changes on reload and that you can visit each page by going to that specific url. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do this. I have found a lot of tutorials and snippets that are half way there but they don't offer the exact functionality.

For example, if you go here: http://lookseewatch.com/independentinsurance/commercial-insurance/

You'll see a long sidebar of different types of commercial insurance they offer. When you click on "Automobile," or any link for that matter, the page should be loaded into the div area on the right of the sidebar. The url then should change to reflect this change to http://lookseewatch.com/independentinsurance/commercial-insurance/automobile/. All of these pages are separate and dynamic in Wordpress.

Can anyone offer me some assistance? This is currently how the sidebar is being generated:

```
wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'');
```

Let me know if you need any other code from me or have any questions about the functionality.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda complicated. There are a lot of ways of catching user events, stopping default behavior and running custom code over it. For exemple, you can listen to anchor clicks and return 0 to not load their links.

But if you change URL in browser address bar, as long as I know, a JS can't control it, because it's outside of a webpage domain, and controling browser components from an external webpage would open a lot of security flaws.

This looks like they wanna avoid banners loading to count less hits :P If performance is the issue, first of all you can use a cache plugin, that will store in HD all DB queries, and use those files in future pageloads instead of making new queries.

You can also build a full sidebar into a PHP variable, cache it in HD and read from there, instead of building the whole code everytime. It will be like adding static HTML snippet.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a technique called pushstate combined with AJAX. There's a great jQuery plugin that's called PJAX that implements this. http://pjax.heroku.com/

I have just published a plugin called WP-PJAX that makes to whole wordpress site PJAX driven. I'm not sure if this solves your problem, but it might be something for you.
https://github.com/pelmered/wp-pjax

Comment: I wanna do something similar, but only with individual WordPress plugins. I left you a comment on your plugin forum. Hope to hear from you!